# Modifying flavors during bottling?

Tags: bottling, flavor, bottle-conditioning, bitterness

Almost two weeks since brew day, hydrometer with the same reading everyday so I guess Sunday will be the bottling day.

I've tried a bit of the beer after taking out some for measurement purposes.

My first batch is a dry brown ale and I asked for non too american hoppy flavor, I do not like it very much (I'm a spaniard living in SF so IPA aroma is driving me crazy xD)

I've noticed that the beer is very bitter, sourness has almost disappeared.

How the flavors change during aging in the bottle? Is the a way to do this bitterness lighter?

I think I'll be ok with this beer, but maybe my partners are expecting kind a malty, sweet result.

Comment: sourness! there shouldn't be any sourness.

Comment: "Sourness" is ambiguous, brewchez. Wheat malt tastes "sour" to me, but I know enough to not use those words when describing it to other brewers. If the "sourness" in this beer went away, then its nothing to worry about and was just a flavor in the green beer.

Comment: When I read "sourness has almost disappeared", I was thinking the bit of aging cleaned-up the sour apple (acetaldehyde) of the 'green' beer.

Comment: Just to add to this post that now we tried the beer, is actually really nice. The final result wasn't as expected thinking in commercial beers.But we are enjoying it a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hop bitterness will decrease somewhat as the beer ages and will also smooth out to a degree.  The dryer the beer is the more the bitterness is going to come through because there isn't much sweetness to balance the bitterness.  There isn't much you can do with the beer at this point other than possibly blending it with a less hoppy or sweeter beer before bottling.
In the future if you want to decrease the bitterness you will have to decrease the quantity of the bittering hop addition(60 minute addition) or use hops with lower alpha acid percentages.  You can also increase the amount of crystal malts used to increase the nonfermentable sugars.  Using a less attenuative yeast strain could also leave the beer sweeter in the finish balancing the hop bitterness.